# Error: No rule to make target `pnacl/Release/nacl_io.stamp', needed by `pnacl/Release/udpclient_unstripped.bc

Tags: google-nativeclient

I'm trying to access socket related APIs using the nacl_io library. To test things out, I've written a sample UDPClient.cpp and added it to the "getting_started/part2" tutorial and modified the Makefile accordingly. I've also added a manifest.json file which I've based on the "examples/demo/nacl_io" project's manifest file.

My Makefile looks like this:

```
VALID_TOOLCHAINS := pnacl

NACL_SDK_ROOT ?= $(abspath $(CURDIR)/../..)

include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk

CHROME_ARGS += --allow-nacl-socket-api=localhost

TARGET = udpclient
DEPS = nacl_io
LIBS = nacl_io ppapi_cpp ppapi pthread

CFLAGS = -Wall
SOURCES = hello_tutorial.cc \
            UDPClient.cpp

# Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:

$(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))

ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
$(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
else
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
endif

$(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))
```

And this is my manifest.json (I've deleted the "keys" and "oauth2" entries, not sure if they're required):

```
{
  "name": "UDPClient",
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "35.0.1916.114",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "UDP client test",
  "offline_enabled": false,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    {
        "socket": [
            "resolve-host"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

When I run make on this project, this is the error I'm getting:

```
  CXX  pnacl/Release/hello_tutorial.o
  CXX  pnacl/Release/UDPClient.o
make: *** No rule to make target `pnacl/Release/nacl_io.stamp', needed by `pnacl/Release/udpclient_unstripped.bc'.  Stop.
```

What is the reason behind this error?

Some additional info: The function within UDPClient.cpp is not actually called yet, and hence I haven't initialized nacl_io using nacl_io_init. I just want it to successfully compile first. The UDPClient is based on this: http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/examples/sockets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. This line was missing from my Makefile:

```
$(foreach dep,$(DEPS),$(eval $(call DEPEND_RULE,$(dep))))
```

Added it below "# Build rules generated..."

Edit: You can also remove the "DEPS" line entirely, as it's only necessary if you're making changes to nacl_io itself. Thanks @binji for pointing that out.

Comment: You can also remove nacl_io from the DEPS line. This is really only useful when making changes to nacl_io. If you are using the library normally, you can leave it off.

Comment: Yes, I realized that later on. Thanks. :)